# php explode on xml file

Tags: php, xml, explode

Here is the xml file I have. ( I do not have editing abilities of the parser that creates this file... so hince why I am asking my question below).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<JobSearchResults LookID="arkansas">
<!-- Served from qs-b-02.oc.careercast.com -->
<QueryString>clientid=arkansas&amp;stringVar=xmlString&amp;pageSize=200&amp;searchType=featured&amp;outFormat=xml</QueryString>
<channel>
<title>JobsArkansas Listings</title>
<items></items>
</channel>
<item>
     <JobID>73451732</JobID>
     <Title>Radiology</Title>
     <Employer>Baptist-Health         </Employer>
     <Location>LITTLE ROCK, AR</Location>
     <Description><![CDATA[IMMEDIATE OPENINGS for:Diabetes Patient Educator, RN Community Education Nurse-RN Baptist Health Community Outreach•Diabetes Patient Educator, RN: Full-time: 8am-5pm Minimum Requirements:•Requires graduation from a state approved school/college of Nursing•Current licensure by theAR State Board of Nursing. •2+ years bedside experience preferred. •Certified Diabetes Educator certificate preferred. •Community Education Nurse - RNMinimum Requirements (PRN: Varies):•Current RN license & 2 years clinical experience. •Current CPR certification. Apply online at: baptist-health.com/jobs]]></Description>
     <LookID>arkansas</LookID>
     <Url>http://jobs.arkansasonline.com/careers/jobsearch/detail/jobId/73451732/viewType/featured</Url>
  </item>
    <item>
     <JobID>66703190</JobID>
     <Title>Telemarketing Agents</Title>
     <Employer>Arkansas Democrat Gazette         </Employer>
     <Location>Bryant, AR</Location>
     <Description><![CDATA[Telemarketing Agents Needed Position is part-time Starting at $9.00/hour Plus Bonus! Looking for dependable and professional applicants. We are a drug and smoke free company located in Bryant. Hours: Mon-Fri 4:30pm to 8:30pm and Sat. 9am to 6pm. Send resumes to: clewis@wehco.com or P.O. Box 384 Bryant, AR 72089 Arkansas Democrat Gazette Arkansas' Largest NewspaperCLICK THE IMAGE TO VIEW THE AD]]></Description>
     <LookID>arkansas</LookID>
     <Url>http://jobs.arkansasonline.com/careers/jobsearch/detail/jobId/66703190/viewType/featured</Url>
  </item>
</JobSearchResults>
sas</LookID>
         <Url>http://jobs.arkansasonline.com/careers/jobsearch/detail/jobId/73004973/viewType/featured</Url>
      </item>

</JobSearchResults>
```

I am using the following php code to open the above xml file, and take out the following:
    
        sas
                 http://jobs.arkansasonline.com/careers/jobsearch/detail/jobId/73004973/viewType/featured

```
</JobSearchResults>
```

However the php code below:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Load File
// $today = date('Ymd');
$file = '/Users/jasenburkett/Sites/jobsark/feed' . '.xml';
$newfile = '/Users/jasenburkett/Sites/jobsark/feed' . '.xml';

$file_contents = file_get_contents($file);

$data = $file_contents;

$parts = explode("</JobSearchResults>", $data);

// Save File
file_put_contents($newfile, $data);

?>
```

This works, however it deletes everything after the first     `</JobSearchResults>` and I want to keep the very last one...

Any ideas where i am going wrong?

Comment: That code will write all the contents of the original file `$data` not `$parts`.

Comment: <?php

 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 // Load File
 // $today = date('Ymd');
 $file = '/Users/jasenburkett/Sites/jobsark/feed' . '.xml';
 $newfile = '/Users/jasenburkett/Sites/jobsark/feed' . '.xml';

 $file_contents = file_get_contents($file);

 $file_contents = $file_contents;
 $parts = explode("</JobSearchResults>", $file_contents);

 $file_contents = $parts['0'];

 // Save File
 file_put_contents($newfile, $file_contents);

?>

Comment: Please post your code as an edit to your question. Code blocks look horrible in comments.

Comment: I tried, sorry. Not an avid user of stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are looking for is a way to cleanup the corrupt XML file, you can just add the string that gets missing when the explode is run. It is all a bit hackish, but it works.

```
$file = '/Users/jasenburkett/Sites/jobsark/feed.xml';
$data = file_get_contents($file);

$split = "</JobSearchResults>";   // Split on this
$parts = explode($split, $data);  // Make the split
$cleanedXml = $parts[0];          // Use first part
$cleanedXml .= $split;            // Put back last ending tag

file_put_contents($file, $cleanedXml);
```

Comment: Thank you, Iwill try that now, and update if works. I appreciate your help, more than you know.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that... It wont let me press the up arrow... and I do not see an 'accept this answer' button. sorry I am fairly new to stack..  Never mind, I am really an idiot. lol.

Comment: I have another question.... Regarding the initial one. Your (mhall) answer worked, but now the issue is the fact that my server is not a php enabled server. So I am having to put the php file on a server that is php enabled, and have it pull in the xml file from a different server. That part works, however the part is the issue is that you have to use curl to run with cron.  Issue is that doing that, you can not use the file_put_contents HTTP wrapper.  

does this make sense? If so, is there a work around to still write to the xml file?

Comment: Say instead of using php, what about going the python route? Thank you in advance

Comment: Well I don't know much about python. You probably should create a new question here on SO for that, so you can reach more people with possible answers.